# Keycloak/Docker Regenerates MySQL Database Tables

Tags: mysql, docker, liquibase, keycloak

I'm working with a docker compose group of services:

- Keycloak
- MySQL

This is a fairly basic setup.  I'm just testing out some things with Keycloak.

What I observe is that on occasion, when I restart all services, Keycloak will fail and complain about the liqubase dbchangelog tables not being present.  But when I check for the tables, they're there.

What appears to be happening is that something is causing Keycloak to regenerate the database tables (via Liquibase).  I can work around this by  keeping MySQL running all the time and only starting and stopping Keycloak, but in the event that someone else is working with this and accidentally stops all the services, they could lose everything in the Keycloak tables.

Two questions:

- Why is this happening?  Why does Keycloak think the tables don't exist?  Is there a race condition between Keycloak and MySQL?  I was under the impression that "depends_on" should cause docker to wait until MySQL has started before starting Keycloak
- Is there a Keycloak setting to disable the automatic creation of the tables?  Even better, is there a env variable that I can set in my docker-compose file that will disable this?

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
    - "3319:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: keycloak
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
   volumes:
    - ~/test/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:4.6.0.Final
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
      DB_ADDR: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: INFO
      ROOT_LOGLEVEL: INFO
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      JDBC_PARAMS: "useSSL=false"
    ports:
    - "6982:8080"
```

Comment: This is still an issue I think right.